# Angular ERROR in TypeError: Cannot read property 'flags' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

estoy teniendo problemas al crear un nuevo projecto en Angular , ya había creado algunos y me funcionaban sin problema , pero ahora quiero crear un nuevo projecto y me sale ese error al poner ng serve
Ya intente borrar el projecto y crear uno nuevo pero me sigue saliendo el mismo error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Es recomendable actualizar su angular y versión de nodejs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tenia el mismo problema, y con las indicaciones que dio Neiber se soluciona, instalando Angular 8.3.3 con el comando npm install -g @angular/cli@8.3.3 , debe existir alguna incompatibilidad entre las ultimas versiones de angular y node

Comment: Si me funciono , desinstale la versión que tenia e instale la versión 8.3.3 y me funciono , muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

A mí me está pasando lo mismo desde hace rato, ya reinstalé node y angular y nada, al crear el proyecto me genera warnings pero lo hace, pero al momento de correrlo me manda ese mismo error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[SOLUCION]
Regresar a una versión anterior de Angular o instalar la más reciente (next - 10.x.x), es una solución a final de cuentas básica.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

`npm upgrade -g @angular/cli`

Con el código anterior, lo actualizan.

Quizás, en caso de que lo anterior no les funcione, ¿qué podría estar sucediendo? Seguramente el node no es compatible con la última versión de angular o viceversa.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahí hay una lista de la compatiblidad entre, angular-cli/angular/nodeJS/typeScript.

De igual forma, pueden probar los siguiente en su CMS global.

`npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest`

Igual, para actualizar la versión de tu proyecto local, dentro , debe ser seleccionado y darle mayor prioridad. Tomando esa carpeta como la única y abrir tu CMS ahí.

Answer (score 0):

Tenía exactamente el mismo problema, reinstale node y angular dos veces y persistía la falla. Finalmente decidí instalar angular 8.3.3 y funcionó correctamente. Supongo hay un bug o alguna incompatibilidad de dependencias.